# "Chip Select Bar" - proper jargon or a place to have some beers at?

Tags: jargon

Today, I came across [a data sheet for an ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc161s626.pdf) (cf. p. 2) including a pin list with the "barred" (i.e. overlined) letters CS, indicating negative logic for the Chip Select pin, followed by the name that had the word "Bar" spelled out.:

\$\overline{CS}\$ = Chip Select Bar

This seems strange to me. To this day, I have always called this pin "Chip Select" - and in writing, I might use "Chip Select (negative logic)" or something similar, and the only time I would probably spell out the word "Bar" would be when talking to the person who typesets the data sheet. Outside the context of typesetting, this rather sounds like a funny name for a bar where you can meet EEs after work. But - I'm not a native speaker.

Surprisingly for me, [searching for the term "Chip Select Bar"](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Chip%20Select%20Bar%22) produces tons of results, the first one being [an application note by a reputable company](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/56755538964965031881813AN_877.pdf) where you can not oly read the words "Chip Select Bar", you even find a pin labeled "CSB" where I would have expected "!CS" in case the typesetting software wouldn't allow \$\overline{CS}\$. It's the very first time I see the letter B as a symbol for negative logic, and this surprises me even more than the spelled-out word "Bar". And in the application note, they are talking about an active low signal, aren't they: "CHIP SELECT BAR (CSB) - CSB is an active low control ..." (cf. p. 3).

Now... is it possible that spelling out the bar in the symbol for negative logic has really become a synonym for negative logic and even replaces "‾" or "!" as a symbol when a pin name is abbreviated, as in CSB? It appears that this habit might cause more confusion than it helps, doesn't it? Is the word "bar" really a commonly used synonym for "active low"?

---

Loosely citing The Doors: *"♫ Well, show me the way. ♫ To the Chip Select Bar. ♫ Oh, don't ask why. ♫ Oh, don't ask why..."*

P.S. Please excuse the title and my idea that I might get some beers at the Chip Select Bar; I actually intend to ask a serious question about proper jargon.

Comment: IME, we often say "chip select bar" in speech, but we never write it out that way.

Comment: The people I usually work with read it as: "low active chip select".

Comment: Electronics is a global industry and it's quite possible that the author of that datasheet wasn't a native English speaker either (even though TI is a US company).  I agree with you, it's poor style, and no "bar" is not a common verbal synonym for "active low".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation with the bar, \$\overline{a},\$ is not from an engineering context originally.
It is a notation used in the context of logic as a mathematical field of research.

In that context, the line above a symbol to indicate negation is indeed pronounced "bar".
For the pronounciation of various notations of negation, see the table in the section "Notation" of [Wikipedia: Negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation).

It does make sense to use this notation of negation here, actually **because** it is pronounced "bar": Most other notations are pronounced by a prefix "not".
In the contexts "CS bar" is used, "not CS" in it's place would often be ambiguous:

**"Hey, wait, not not x, not y!"**

versus

**"Hey, wait, not x bar, y bar!"**

Regarding spelling it out, I think it's really the backup option in case you can not write the \$\overline{a}\$ for typesetting (or keyboard) reasons.

Note that you can not just leave it out when speaking:

Saying

> Connect this to chip select because...

is clearly understandable,
but

> Connect these to x and y because...

when you have pins \$\overline{x}\$ and \$y\$ is less clear.  Should I put a inverter gate in between for x?

And it's not clear at all when you have pins \$x\$ and \$\overline{x}\$.

That \$\overline{CS}\$ spoken as "chip select" works well depends a lot on context information. And in part, it's simply because you do not care whether it's inverted or not in many situations.

Comment: +1, I'm a fan of etymology (and I do remember my math classes I took during my years of EE studies). Agreed, in Math, it's common to say "x dot" or "y bar". However, I've found some more sources from the EE context that really make it confusing. If you search for "CSBAR" in this document (http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/eng_bulletin/EB261.pdf), you'll find: "Each chip select pin has an associated base address register (CSBAR)...". Now, that's a register acronym, but we learn it's really all about context... No negation, no active low there...

Comment: @zebonaut Hmm... as that variant is an acronym for "Chip Select Base Address Register", I'd say it's just bad luck they are the same. And the acronym is probably invented by someone not used to pronouncing or spelling it "CS bar"...

Comment: Thinking again about the usage in Math: I remember having said or heard terms like "x dot" or "y bar" hundreds, if not thousands of times. But in writing? Maybe once or twice, at best, and this would have been in footnotes saying something like "pronounced 'ex dot'" / "pronounced 'wye bar'" But in writing, as part of the main text? Not that I can remember. Reading "Chip Select Bar" really feels like someone used a dictaphone and someone else typed it without further thought.

Comment: @zebonaut There is an interesting point: We say "see ess bar", and we may write "CS bar". But that does not mean we need to say or write "Chip Select bar": "CS" is the short form of "Chip Select", and bar is the short form of expressing negaion. The short forms go well together, and with "Chip Select", we'd use one of the possible long forms to express negation, fiting the context: "Chip Select inverted", "not Chip Select", and even just "Chip Select" - with implicit negation!

Comment: @zebonaut Appart from that, I think writing CS bar etc is completely caused by the person who typed it missing a bar key or a bar character at hand. And at hand means something like "with one or two keystrokes". And, by the way, I have to admit that in vim, I do not know the keystrokes for the character a with bar above. All I know is it's possible in gvim.

Comment: I notice that in the question, you say you expect about the same as I described, but see other uses "in the field" - like in real manuals and data sheets, and search engines indexing data sheets. Based on the reasoniing above, I see "Chip Select bar" as an error, (but one that is easy to make, because it's not obvious) And with the Analog Devices application note from the first search match, there's more broken in terms of notation: They actually label the pin "CSB" - without bar (as you all point out in your question) - so the word "bar" is not even refering to a bar here!

Answer (score 7):

There's no "standard" way of representing an active-low signal.  I have seen various combinations of: \$\overline{CS}\$, \$nCS\$, \$!CS\$, \$CS\#\$, \$\_CS\$, \$CSB\$, etc.  All of them mean the same thing "Active-Low Chip Select". Myself I prefer to use \$\overline{CS}\$ given the choice, or if the typesetting software won't allow it (I use \$\LaTeX\$ for all my datasheet typesetting so it does allow it) then \$CS\#\$. But it tends to be largely a matter of personal choice, what someone was taught at university, or maybe even regional conventions (I notice a number of the search results are for German sites).

I've never seen the word Bar spelled out before either though, but in a textual context it does make a certain amount of sense if you can't do a real bar, since you could say "See Ess Bar" in speech.

Answer (score 3):

It just seems so ... clunky. Not only does it not make sense to write out "Bar" it doesn't make sense (but perhaps it is still more sensical) to even pronounce the BAR as bar, it is the inversion or NOT operator after all. So \$\overline{CS}\$, \$nCS\$, \$!CS\$, \$CS\#\$, \$\_CS\$, \$CSB\$ are all pronounced "not See Ess".

However, what language is completely consistent?

Comment: I would be inclined to pronounce the aformentioned pin as either "cee ess bar" or "active-low chip select".  What I find odd is the expansion of the letters as "chip select" without expanding "bar" to something like "active low".

Comment: @supercat active-low sounds good too